# Material-Table Something went wrong error

Tags: material-table

I am using Material-table in my project. When I reload the grid I get a something went wrong error message displayed.
I installed this package:
yarn add material-table
yarn add @material-ui/core

> I am getting the DevTools was disconnected from the page error.

Error Screenshot:

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Any console errors? Can you provide a minimal example that replicates the issue? Is the error aparent in different browsers? There is no way we can help you with the (lack) of information provided.

Comment: I am getting any console error.  I updated full screenshot

Comment: I am using chrome browser

Comment: Does it happen in other browsers though?